# Conditional plot from a data set

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have the data:

```
data={{r,a,b},{0,1.06471,1.16909},{1,1.06463,1.169},{2,1.06456,1.06456},{3,1.06448,1.16884},{4,1.0644,1.16875},{5,1.06433,1.06433},{6,1.06425,1.06425},{7,1.06418,1.1685},{8,1.0641,1.16841}}
```

I want to draw a thick yellow line when a=b and a thick red line when a>b or b>a, for each value of r. The output will look something like this (for a larger dataset):
[image]

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any documentation for `ConditionalPlot`. Where did you run across that symbol?

Comment: Oh! then that does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We first evaluate the colors by:

```
data = {{0, 1.06471, 1.16909}, {1, 1.06463, 1.169}, {2, 1.06456, 
    1.06456}, {3, 1.06448, 1.16884}, {4, 1.0644, 1.16875}, {5, 
    1.06433, 1.06433}, {6, 1.06425, 1.06425}, {7, 1.06418, 
    1.1685}, {8, 1.0641, 1.16841}};
dat = data /. {r_, a_, b_} -> {r, If[a == b, Yellow, Red]}
```

[image]

And now we draw the lines:

```
Graphics[{Thickness[0.12], #[[2]], Line[{{#[[1]], 0}, {#[[1]], 1}}]} & /@ dat]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the error: " Coordinate {$CellContext`r, 0} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form. "

Comment: Did you eliminate the first sublist: {r,a,b} in your data?

Comment: Oh yes, it works now. How can I check for the sign of a and b and not their magnitude? (If sign(a)=sign(b) then yellow line, if not equal then a red line) @Daniel Huber

Comment: Try If[Sign[a]== Sign[b],...]

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you so much! @Daniel Huber

Answer (score 8):

Transform `data` into a list of colors:

```
colorlist = data[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]] /. { {a_, a_} -> Yellow, {_, _} -> Red}
```

[image]

#### 1. ArrayPlot

You can use `colorlist` as the first argument of [`ArrayPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html)

```
ArrayPlot[{colorlist}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

`MatrixPlot[{colors}]` gives a similar result.

#### 2. Image

Alternatively, use it in the first argument of  [`Image`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html):

```
Image[{colorlist}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

#### 3. Raster + Graphics

Finally, you can use it with a combination of [`Raster`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Raster.html) and [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html):

```
Graphics[Raster[{List @@@ colorlist}], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You could start with something like this:

```
ArrayPlot[{Boole[Equal @@@ data[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]]}, ColorRules -> {1 -> Yellow, 0 -> Red}]
```

Looks like we can force it to work with True|False values:

```
ArrayPlot[{Equal @@@ data[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]}, ColorRules -> {True -> Yellow, False -> Red}]
```

Comment: As I increase the dataset, the plot is getting extremely thin.

Comment: @Math_student, use [`AspectRatio`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html) option.

Answer (score 6):

```
dt = Join[#, #, #, #, #] &[Rest @ data];

MatrixPlot[{Boole[#[[2]] == #[[3]] & /@ dt]}, 
 ColorRules -> {1 -> Yellow, 0 -> Red}, AspectRatio -> 1/4]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Using `ImageAssemble`:**

```
cols = If[Equal[#[[2]], #[[3]]], Yellow, Red] & /@ (Rest@data)
ImageAssemble[ConstantImage[#, {20, 50}] & /@ cols]
```

[image]